# C++ access to function argument private variable

Tags: c++, oop

```
 class Container{



private:
    int num_;

public:

    Container(): num_(1)
    {};

    void add(Container other){
        num_+=other.num_;
    }

    int get_num(){
        return num_;
    }

    void set_num(int n){
        num_=n;
    }
```

};

In the above example other.num_ is accessible... Why? Shouldn`t it be unaccessible due to the private modifier?

Comment: No, the *class* has access to its own private members.

Comment: because you're accessing it from class Container

Comment: Because in C++ encapsulation is per class, not per object. It means that any object of type Container can access private members, it doesn't matter if they're in a different object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can always access it's own member, whatever access modifier a member variable it has.
`private`: only the class can access 
`protected`: only derived classes can access
`public`: everyone can access

If you write:

```
class Container{
private:
    int num_;
}
```

Every object can access private members of any other object of same class because in `c++` access modifier is for a class not for each object of that class.